# Why is this mileage marker in British Columbia placed exactly 111km away, seemingly in the middle of nowhere?

Tags: road-signs

While driving from Alberta to British Columbia, we noticed [a road sign stating that Prince George was 111km away](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.7905962,-121.265073,3a,15y,337.14h,93.24t/data=!3m9!1e1!3m7!1sGmZLvicjYSBlH8Jvd1x-KQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!9m2!1b1!2i17):

[image: A green British Columbia road sign that says Prince George is 111km away.]

We wondered why this specific road sign had been placed at a specific mileage of 111km, seemingly in the middle of nowhere. There aren't any cities or stops nearby that would incentivize a road sign specifically here at the 111km point.

It's expected that there are *some* reminder road signs that tell you how far away the next major city is, but why here? Some highway planner would have drafted up a road sign to go specifically here for *some* reason, right? They wouldn't have paid to build and install a sign unless there was some reason to.

Is there perhaps a law that requires road signs in British Columbia to be placed after a certain number of kilometers? Is this just an equidistant spot between some points of interest? What motivates the placement of this type of road sign on a British Columbian highway?

Comment: It isn't the result of the change from miles to km either, 111 km is 69 miles (not a nice round number).

Comment: I suspect (hence not an answer) they reckoned one was due in roughly that area, they put it on a nice straight bit where it wasn't a distraction and a crew could work safely and easily, and then worked out the distance.

Comment: In UK, sometimes they place a distance marker a little way beyond a junction, then you know you are on the right road. The destination is as important as the distance, perhaps more so.

Comment: `Some highway planner would have drafted up a road sign to go specifically here for some reason` engineers and planners have their own way of "humor" sometimes. perhaps 111 seemed better than 110 or 100 for the planner.

Comment: The answer is probably to be found in the [*Manual of Uniform Traffic Control Devices for Canada*](https://www.tac-atc.ca/en/publications-and-resources/mutcdc), which sets standards for road signage.  Unfortunately it costs CAD 575, but maybe some library near you has a copy.  [The USA's version](https://mutcd.fhwa.dot.gov/pdfs/2009r1r2/pdf_index.htm) is free though and might have similar provisions that would shed light.

Comment: @WeatherVane that’s common in many countries, but here there are no junctions close by.

Comment: The US's guidance for "distance signs" is Section 2D.42 of the MUTCD: "If used, Distance signs should be installed on important routes leaving municipalities and just beyond
intersections of numbered routes in rural areas. If used, they should be placed just outside the municipal limits
or at the edge of the built-up area if it extends beyond the limits."  But that doesn't seem to fit the location of this sign.  So maybe Canada has other rules, or just didn't follow them in this instance.

Comment: Or...perhaps...someone on the road crew was just amused by the idea, and acted on it.

Comment: 111 km corresponds roughly to 1 degree, or 60 nautical miles, but that could be just a coincidence. (40000000 / 360 = 111111.111...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Destination distance signs are supposed to be placed

> Approximately every 20km between destinations or 40km intervals for highways that lie north of 54° latitude.

Source: BC's [Manual of Standard Traffic Signs and Pavement Markings (PDF)](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/assets/gov/driving-and-transportation/transportation-infrastructure/engineering-standards-and-guidelines/traffic-engineering-and-safety/traffic-engineering/traffic-signs-and-pavement-markings/manual_signs_pavement_marking.pdf), chapter 4, page 4.8.

(More resources are available at the BC Ministry of Transportation and Infrastructure's page [Traffic Signs & Pavement Markings](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/transportation/transportation-infrastructure/engineering-standards-guidelines/traffic-engineering-safety/traffic-signs-markings).)

This highway is just south of 54 degrees north latitude, but I could not find another sign either 20 km west of this one nor 40 km west.  But I did find one that is (nominally) exactly 100 km to the east, which appears to have been placed [just west](https://maps.app.goo.gl/3BrbxEHWvsxcZhth7) of [McBride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McBride%2C_British_Columbia) in keeping with the instruction to install these signs

> Approximately 200 to 300m beyond the developed area departing
> an incorporated municipality

I suspect that this is the reason for the placement of the sign that you found.

Comment: In northern Ontario, which also has highways through long stretches of not-much-going-on, they don't have many destination distance signs like that [but do have frequent kilometer posts](https://maps.app.goo.gl/sziooLXbZSYYKGKu7) to let you know where you are and tell someone else where they can find you. I haven't found any of those on that BC highway, so maybe they use destination distance signs for the same purpose?